# error in my code MVC5 Angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I wanted to get the dropdownlist index to interact the database through jsonresult, but when I change the dropdownlist no action generated , here is the code.

```
(function () {
            //Create a Module 
            var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']); // Will use ['ng-Route'] 

        //implement routing

        })();
```

this code for get dropdownlist index

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('CommandeControllerClt', function ($scope, LocationService) {


               $scope.Id_Partenaire = null; 
               $scope.PartenaireList = null; 



               // Function For Populate  partnerers 
               $scope.GetPartenaire = function () {

                   //Load State 
                   LocationService.GetPartenaire($scope.Id_Partenaire).then(function (d) {
                       alert(d.data);  
                   }, function (error) {
                       alert('Error!');
                   });

               }

           })
        .factory('LocationService', function ($http) { // explained about factory in Part2
            var fac = {};

            fac.GetPartenaire = function (Id_Partenaire) {
                return $http.get('/CommandeClt/GetPartenaire?Id_CltOrigine=' + Id_Partenaire)
            }

            return fac;
        });
```

jsonResult

```
public JsonResult GetPartenaire(int Id_CltOrigine)
         {

var Nom_CltOrigine = MetiersRepository.ClientSearch(Id_CltOrigine).Select(s => new Partenaire() { Cd_Partenaire = s.Cd_Partenaire, Adresse_Societe = s.Adresse_Societe }).ToList();

    return new JsonResult { Data = Nom_CltOrigine, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
         }
```

Code Rezor , the dropdownlist have already binded

```
    <select name="Id_Partenaire" ng-model="Id_Partenaire" 
ng-options="I.Id_Partenaire as I.Cd_Partenaire for I in PartenaireList" 
    ng-change="GetState()">
                   @{
        foreach (var c in ViewBag.SelectedClientOption) 
        {
                    <option value="@c.Id_Partenaire">@c.Cd_Partenaire</option>
        }
         }
     </select>
```

Comment: Do you have GetState method in angular? I can't see it!

Comment: thank you Volkan Akın Paşa  for your answer ,GetState() = GetPartenaire ,I rectify this error, despite this the problem has not yet solved

Comment: what do you mean 'no action generated '? in browser's console can you see that you are requesting the url /CommandeClt/GetPartenaire? also if you see the request can you see any response?

Comment: yes when i see the firefox  inspector not request has been

Comment: I don't get it! Can you see /CommandeClt/GetPartenaire? Yes or No? 
And Can you see any response as well?

Comment: no i can't see GetPartenaire and no reponse

Comment: i think i should find other way to get index dropdwonlist by angular, becouse this is failed way

Comment: Because you don't call the method in your factory. I edited your code an works https://plnkr.co/edit/xqgWhle09fAb5enKaIyv?p=preview

Comment: i will try to edited my code based  of your suggestion and i will answer u

Comment: tnx  Volkan Akın Paşa , but  i have changed my code , i wish to success in  this time